# Exception accessing FormatCondition using VS2010 and Excel 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel, excel-interop

I get the following exception when I try to access a FormatCondition item from a FormatConditions collection.

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.FormatCondition'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00024425-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

I'm using VS2010 SP1, C#, Excel 2010 32 bit

So far I created an excel spreadsheet and added Conditional Formatting to cell B3.

In code I:

1. open the spreadsheet.
2. get cell b3
3. verify that FormatConditions.Count returns 1.

I get the above exception when I try the following:

```
fmtCond = (Excel.FormatCondition) testCell.FormatConditions.Item(1);
```

The code I'm using seems to work fine when build w/VS2005 and Excel 2007 on another PC.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to grab all of the format conditions together, I've found it works when you set the properties individually:

```
DestRange.FormatConditions.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue, SourceRange.FormatConditions(1).Operator, SourceRange.FormatConditions(1).Formula1)

DestRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = SourceRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex
```

where `DestRange` and `SourceRange` are the region you are transferring the properties to, and the original range, respectively.  You may need to grab additional properties of the `FormatConditions` if you have specified them.